# why xampp is listening on port localhost/dashboard instead on port localhost:8080

Tags: xampp, localhost, port

I installed xampp on my windows 10. Here the problem is when ever i try to access

> localhost:8080
>   it response something like this

```
site cannot be reached
```

But if I try directly without like using any port something like this

> localhost/dashboard
>   This is accessible

I want to know what is the problem here why localhost:8080 is not reached.
and How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that if you change your Main Apache Server port from 80 (or default) to 8080, you will also need to change your URL from "localhost/" to "localhost:8080"

After you update your port and once you enter the correct URL you should be able to access your PHP MySQL. If you can, but are unable to access Word Press installation, you may want to check out this helpful link on updating your Port Values in your localhost Database for WordPress.

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-wordpress-site-not-working-on-localhost-after-port-change-9373